# How to pass data- attribute to @Html.CheckBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to use @Html.CheckBoxFor to produce this HTML:

```
<input checked="checked" data-val="true" id="IsActive" name="IsActive" data-off="Inactive" data-on="Active" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

If I use:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsActive, new {  data-on="Active", data-off="Inactive" })
```

My code does not compile.

and if I use:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsActive, new {  on="Active", off="Inactive" })
```

I don't get the expected: **data**-off="Inactive" **data**-on="Active" in the output HTML.

The reason I need **data-on** and **data-off** is that, it is what my library [bootstraptoggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) is expecting.

Comment: `new { data_on="Active", data_off="Inactive }` - you need to use an underscore (which will then be converted to a hyphen in the generated html

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen, it worked.